# Create a simple select funtion in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a simple SQL function that will select and return records, I am doing this as I have to use this function at several places in my stored procedure.Am doing this to avoid the entire select query in the Stored Procedure.

```
create function udf_SelectNews
Begin
    select top 10 
        ID, Headline, CreatedDate 
    from tblNews 
    order by CreatedDate DESC
End
```

Getting error near select

Comment: So, what is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline Table Function:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cf3cb/1/0)**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_SelectNews()
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
  (SELECT TOP 10 ID,Headline,CreatedDate
  FROM tblNews
  ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC);
```

Answer (score 1):

- you missed schema reference and function syntax `()`
- Return Type should be defined
- No need for Begin and End
- function should `return` the result.

  ```
  create function dbo.udf_SelectNews()
  returns table
  AS
  return
  select top 10 ID,Headline,CreatedDate from tblNews order by CreatedDate DESC
  ```